# Dúvida sobre $.getJSON e history.pushState

Tags: html5-history

Estou estudando sobre history.pushState e pretendo desenvolver um site como forma de estudo como este http://html5.gingerhost.com/

Em relação ao jQuery (função para carregar o novo conteúdo) eu entendi perfeitamente, mas me surgiram algumas dúvidas:

1. Existe diferença entre `window.history.pushState` ou somente `history.pushState`?
2. Qual a função do primeiro atributo (nesse caso "null") `window.history.pushState(null, "titulo", "novaurl")`?
3. O segundo atributo, responsável pelo novo título, não funciona. Proceder com `document.title = "novoTitulo"` é a forma correta?
4. No caso do cite citado como exemplo, utiliza-se `$.getJSON` para retornar os dados solicitados, e essa parte eu até entendi como retornar os dados do PHP, mas, minha grande dúvida é: se eu possuo um site grande, como vou retornar todos os dados sendo que eu utilizo Templates para auxílio do PHP e HTML (incluindo consultas ao banco, e etc), isso é possível ou terei que mudar minha estrutura? Pois, pelo que percebi os dados retornados são de acordo com a variável `cid` passada através do jQuery, e os dados são retornados com um `echo json_encode()...`?
5. Há mesmo incompatibilidade da função `window.history.pushState()` com o IE?
6. Já vi no Github uma biblioteca chamada [History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/). Pra que ela serve já que a função history já é nativa dos navegadores (estou perguntando porque realmente não consegui entender)?

**Obrigado!**

Comment: Igor, o assunto do getJSON é totalmente independente da questão do histórico. Sugiro você tirar isso da pergunta e postar como uma pergunta separada.

Comment: Sim, eu sei, acontece que como no exemplo que citei essa função é utilizada, gostaria de saber se a mesma poderia ser utilizada em sites grandes, como citei na pergunta...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vou responder ponto a ponto sobre a parte do histórico. Quanto ao `getJSON`, acho que é caso para uma pergunta separada, como eu já disse no comentário acima (não leve a mal, somos malucos por organização aqui no site, e o ideal é que as perguntas sejam focadas, para que possam ajudar a outras pessoas).

> Existe diferença entre `window.history.pushState` ou somente `history.pushState`?

Não. Nos browsers, `window` é o objeto global. Tudo o que está pendurado em `window` pode ser acessado com ou sem o `window.`.

> Qual a função do primeiro atributo (nesse caso "null") `window.history.pushState(null, "titulo", "novaurl")`?

Isso é uma das coisas mais interessantes da API de histórico. Você pode passar um objeto que representa o estado da aplicação naquele dado momento. Quando a pessoa retorna àquele ponto (via botão "voltar" do browser, por exemplo), é disparado um evento `popstate`, e o *listener* desse evento recebe o objeto de estado correspondente. Assim você pode restaurar o estado da aplicação sem precisar buscar dados no servidor.

O objeto a ser passado deve ser um objeto simples que possa ser serializado (ou seja, sem funções/métodos, e eu também evitaria conteúdo herdado via protótipo). O objeto serializado deve ocupar no máximo 640k caracteres.

> O segundo atributo, responsável pelo novo título, não funciona. Proceder com `document.title = "novoTitulo"` é a forma correta?

O objetivo do segundo argumento para `pushState` não é alterar o título da página, e sim gravar um título no histórico. Se quer alterar o título atual, de fato precisa usar `document.title = "novoTitulo"`.

> Há mesmo incompatibilidade da função `window.history.pushState() com o IE?

Sim, pelo que sei só está disponível a partir do IE10.

> Já vi no Github uma biblioteca chamada History.js. Pra que ela serve já que a função history já é nativa dos navegadores (estou perguntando porque realmente não consegui entender)?

O objetivo é justamente oferecer algo próximo à API oficial em browser onde ela não é suportada, como versões do IE anteriores à 10. A biblioteca usa mecanismos de *fallback* como *hashes* para lidar com os estados e trocas de URL.

### Documentação relevante:

- [**Guia de uso da History API, MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)
- [**Especificação**](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#history)

Comment: Obrigado por responder. Somente mais uma pequena dúvida. Então vale a pena utilizar da biblioteca History.js?